# Display Contents of List Result of XML Parse Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, rss

Trying to figure out how to access the XML that was parsed with Groovy into a list of items.

Here is the what is in of one of the list items:

> [item[attributes={}; value=[title[attributes={}; value=[Penn State provides update on teaching modes for summer and fall 2021]], link[attributes={}; value=[https://news.psu.edu/story/648884/2021/02/24/academics/penn-state-provides-update-teaching-modes-summer-and-fall-2021]], description[attributes={}; value=[Penn State is planning a phased return over the summer semester to a full on-campus learning environment for fall 2021. The University’s priorities continue to be the health and well-being of its students, faculty, staff and local communities, and the plans for expanded in-person classes have the flexibility built in to quickly respond to changing pandemic conditions, if necessary.
> ]], guid[attributes={isPermaLink=false}; value=[https://news.psu.edu/story/648884/2021/02/24/academics/penn-state-provides-update-teaching-modes-summer-and-fall-2021]], pubDate[attributes={}; value=[Wed, 24 Feb 2021 13:21 -0500]], source[attributes={url=https://news.psu.edu/rss/internal_tags/latest-news}; value=[Penn State News - Latest News]]]]]

I can't get the actual title, link and description. Rather I am getting the entire value with this code:

```
def pennStateNews = news.getNews(1)
println "Penn State News (unformatted):"
println pennStateNews
println "-----------------------------"
println pennStateNews.size()
println "Title is : " + pennStateNews.get(0).title
println "Link is :" + pennStateNews.get(0).link 
println "Description is : " + pennStateNews.get(0).description
```

Here is the output:

> 1
> TITLE IS *********** : [title[attributes={}; value=[Penn State provides update on teaching modes for summer and fall 2021]]]
> LINK IS *********** :[link[attributes={}; value=[https://news.psu.edu/story/648884/2021/02/24/academics/penn-state-provides-update-teaching-modes-summer-and-fall-2021]]]
> DESCRIPTION IS *********** : [description[attributes={}; value=[Penn State is planning a phased return over the summer semester to a full on-campus learning environment for fall 2021. The University’s priorities continue to be the health and well-being of its students, faculty, staff and local communities, and the plans for expanded in-person classes have the flexibility built in to quickly respond to changing pandemic conditions, if necessary.
> ]]]

I want to get the value of the title "Penn State provides update on teaching modes for summer and fall 2021" as well as the link and description and cannot figure how.  Looked all over in forums and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have an XML structured like this (which I think is roughly analogous to what you're working with):

```
def xmlStr = '''
<xml>
    <item> 
       <title>Penn State provides...</title>
       <link>https://news.psu.edu/story/648884...</link>
       <description>Penn State is planning a phased...</description>
       <guid isPermaLink="false">https://news.psu.edu/story/648884/...</guid>
       <pubDate>Wed, 24 Feb 2021 13:21 -0500</pubDate>
       <source url="https://news.psu.edu/rss/internal_tags/latest-news">Penn State News - Latest News</source>
    </item> 
  </xml>'''
```

we can target the node via it's gpath. Once we are successfully in that node, we can call `text()` on the resulting match

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlStr)

assert "Penn State provides..." == xml.item.title.text()
assert "https://news.psu.edu/story/648884..." == xml.item.link.text()
assert "Penn State is planning a phased..." == xml.item.description.text()
```

You can find more info [here on the Groovy docs](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html).